# How can I check the age of a city?

Tags: simcity-4

How do I find out how old a city is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the date on the lower left hand side of the interface. Your city starts in the year 00 (2000).

[image: A screenshot of the lower left corner of SimCity 4's UI, with the clock reading '12/10/73']

The city in the image above, for instance, is 73 years old.

Comment: Oh, then my city is 4 years old, it shows 08/01/04